# webRTC Asterisk getting: "Media stream permission denied"

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, asterisk

We are facing issue while initiating a call from webRTC using chrome "Version 50.0.2661.102 m (64-bit)" to Zoiper SIP Client.

Both users are now connected with webRTC Asterisk server.

Getting error as "Media stream permission denied".

Can anyone please help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: Posting Asterisk version, configurations and logs is the best way to get help.

Comment: Did you try to restart asterisk?

Answer (score 2):

This post is too old, but let me post how we fixed it.

In our case, the user had not granted microphone access to the site. Once microphone access was granted to the site, the issue was resolved.

Also check if the link used is https and that the user has microphone.

Hope this helps, thanks.